# Uniquely identify a device from Vue PWA

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA developed using VueJS. I need to get hold of a unique ID of the device using the app and the ID shouldn't change.

I tried using `@capacitor/device` and getting the device ID by `Device.getId()`. But the issue is since I am using the application from the browser, as soon as I clear my local storage, the device Id changes.

What could be other alternatives for this scenario?

Comment: You can look at @fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs